# python iteration over *args

Tags: python, filter, iteration, args

```
sum_even_values(1,2,3,4,5,6) # 12
sum_even_values(4,2,1,10) # 16
sum_even_values(1) # 0

# define sum_even_values
def sum_even_values(*args):        
    #return sum( x for x in args if x%2==0 )        
    return sum (filter(lambda x: x%2==0, args))
```

> ---return sum ( filter ( args, lambda x : x%2==0))
>
> ---TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Why is it showing me TypeError if args is iterable object and filter wants to give only even numbers for the sum function. 
both returns have to has the same output but the second one is not working. 
it is happening the same with below code.

```
sum_floats(1.5, 2.4, 'awesome', [], 1) # 3.9
sum_floats(1,2,3,4,5) # 0

def sum_floats(*args):    
    #return sum(x for x in args if type(x)==float)
    return sum ( filter ( args, lambda x : type(x)==float))
```

Comment: `filter` must be called as `filter(function, iterable)`: the first parameter must be the filtering function, the second must be an iterable. You cannot change the order of the parameters.

Comment: That advice is true for most functions. Unless it uses named parameters, you have to provide the parameters in the correct order.

Comment: in def sum_even_values() : I have placed the fucntion in the correct postion , still it is showing me the error.